# MultiGPU Blender setup - Running Blender on one and rendering on another

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

Is it possible to run Blender's interface on another GPU? I know you can run it on the integrated GPU, but can you do the same with a multi-GPU setup?

My idea comes from another question I asked recently - because of the high amount of vram the scene needs can't I dedicate 1 GPU to it and let the other handle the rendering, effectivly splitting vram usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign your GPUs for rendering and display separately.
Just go to your User-Preferences, and in the System-Panel under `Cycles Compute Device` assign your secondary GPUs as render device, and disable the card that runs the display for rendering.

[image]

Comment: Nice setup! Lights must flicker in the whole block when you hit `F12` :D

Comment: Didn't realize it would work like that. Thanks!